# Binding to both the checked state and string value of NSCheckBoxes in an NSCollectionView

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nscollectionview

I need to create an `NSCollectionView` which contains `NSCheckBox`es. When I do this for something like labels I can bind to the control's value. But when dealing with NSCheckBoxes I need to bind to *both* its value (checked or unchecked) and it's text string.

I'm don't understand how I can bind two different attributes of an `NSCheckBox`. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A checkbox has both a "Value" binding, which is the state of the checkbox (checked, unchecked, or mixed) and a "Title" binding, which is the label string. You can bind each independently, which is what you want.